# Run jar from bash at /usr/bin throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, bash, jar

I have a jar file located at `/home/ec2-user/Back-end` and I want to make it runnable from everywhere, like a normal command.

So, I created a bash file `myprogram` in `/usr/bin` and I entered my command `java -jar myprogram.jar $*`

I can successfully access my program using the `myprogram` command from everywhere. The only problem is that it throws me a `FileNotFoundException`, because I need to read/write csv files in this program.

It only happens when I'm not in the folder where the jar file is located. So I imagine that it try to read the csv file from the current folder and not from the jar folder, that's my problem. This is how I want to read my csv file, located in the `csv` folder which is in the same folder than my jar file : `new FileReader("csv/"+this.name+".csv")`

I tried the functions sequences from here  [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) and it works in Eclipse but not from the terminal when running the jar (it returns null).

Any way to make the file relative to the jar location and not to my location ? Otherwise I will just set an absolute path, but I think that it's not the best solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which file it's trying to access when it gets this exception. Include the exception stacktrace and the relevant source code from your program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: If the csv files are static include them into the JAR.